# How to calculate diagonal distance on a 3 dimensional grid

Tags: c#, path-finding

I'm trying to adapt [Sebastian Lague's A-Star path finding code](https://github.com/SebLague/Pathfinding) [(youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-L-WgKMFuhE&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0cq5Umv3pMC9SPnKjfp9eGW&index=1) to 3 dimensions. I have it somewhat working but occasionally the path produced between my nodes is sub-optimal, and I think it's because I'm calculating distance wrong.

To move along a single dimension from one node to the next is a distance of 1. To move in 2 dimensions (diagonally) the distance is √2 (which is simplified to 1.4 in the code). These values are multiplied by 10 to keep them as integers, so 10 and 14 respectively.

To calculate the distance on a 2d plane you take the smaller of the X and Y distances and multiply it by 14, then minus the smaller distance from the larger one and multiply what remains by 10.

```
    int dstX = Mathf.Abs(nodeA.gridX - nodeB.gridX);
    int dstY = Mathf.Abs(nodeA.gridY - nodeB.gridY);

    if (dstX > dstY)
    {
        return 14 * dstY + 10 * (dstX - dstY);
    }
    else
        return 14 * dstX + 10 * (dstY - dstX);
```

Moving in 3 dimensions is still a diagonal move, so the distance should still be 14. So moving forward and to the left by one node is no farther than moving *up*, forward, and to the left by one. So rather than take the smallest value and multiply it by 14, I've been taking the middle value and multiplying it by 14. Then I subtract the middle value from the largest value and multiply the remainder by 10.

If X was largest, Y was in the middle, and Z was smallest then whenever I needed to move diagonally  to approach the y value I may as well move toward the Z value at the same time, so I don't think I even need to factor the distance on the Z axis in.

```
    int xDistance = Mathf.Abs(nodeA.gridX - nodeB.gridX);
    int yDistance = Mathf.Abs(nodeA.gridY - nodeB.gridY);
    int zDistance = Mathf.Abs(nodeA.gridZ - nodeB.gridZ);

    int largest = Mathf.Max(xDistance, yDistance, zDistance);
    int middle = GetMiddleValue(xDistance, yDistance, zDistance);
    int smallest = Mathf.Min(xDistance, yDistance, zDistance);

    return 14 * middle + 10 * (largest - middle);
```

For some reason my path still has kinks in it, like it will move down one node before moving back up. [The white line shows the optimal path between the 2 white cubes while the black follows the nodes the path is actually taking.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBmm1.png)

Maybe it's a rounding issue but I'm not super confident I haven't missed anything while calculating the distance.

I've only been coding for 4-5 months, so I apologise if this is really obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, changing location in two dimensions should be based on 14 (10 * square root of 2), but changing in all three dimensions at once should be based on 17 (10 * square root of 3), if my quick math is correct. I suspect that may solve your issue.

(Sure enough...[here's](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-find-the-distance-between-two-opposite-corners-of-a-cube) a short explanation of why it should be based on sqrt(3).)

Comment: Right, ok that makes total sense. Thanks heaps for the help. I fixed up the code so that it is now 17 * smallest + 14 * (middle - smallest) + 10 * (largest - middle - smallest). I'm still getting kinks in the path because my path is too long but the problem must be elsewhere. Thanks again, the pictures really helped.

Answer (score 1):

As Beska said, it should be root(3) in some casesof a 3D space, but why?
pythagore theorem also works in 3D, where distance = root(a² + b² + c²)

In your 3D space if you move in only 1 direction you'll have a distance of root(1² + 0² + 0²) which is 1

if you move in 2 directions, you'll get a root(1² + 1² + 0²) which is root(2)

but if you move in both 3 directons you'll end up with root(1² + 1² + 1²) which is root(3)

hope I got clear :)

Comment: When you word it that way it makes a lot of sense. It's nearly 2am here so my brain is probably not working at full steam, so breaking it down was really helpful. Thanks man.

Comment: No problem, have fun with your project ;D